# Asp.Net core 6 session keys

Tags: c#, session, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I had my project running on .NET framework 4.8 and then I migrated it to .NET 6. Whenever I needed to access specific properties from Session I used:

```
public static bool SIMInside
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)HttpContext.Current.Session["SIMInside"];
            }
            set
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Session["SIMInside"] = value;
            }
        }
```

How can I achieve this in Asp.Net core 6? What I know that I need to add `builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();` in `Program.cs` and then inject to desired location.
I tried but to no avail:

```
public static bool SIMInside
        {
            get
            {
                return _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get("SIMInside");
            }
            set
            {
                _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Set("SIMInside", value);
            }
        }
```

In this case here `Get` returns `byte[]` array or `Set` requires `byte[]` array also

Comment: Default methods accept a serialized object and return a serialized object. If you want to use something else there are two other methods : `SetString`, `SetInt32`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ASP.NET Core has a different way to use session compare to classic ASP.NET Application.

Unfortunately you can no longer store complex objects in it. To store object it is converted into JSON and stored as a string. Later, it is retrieved as a string and deserialized to the original object.

In your case you can use `SetInt32 and GetInt32` to store and retrieve 1 for true an 0 for false and then parse the value.

```
Convert.ToBoolean(session.GetInt32(“SIMInside”));

session.SetInt32(“SIMInside”, Convert.ToInt32(value));
```

Don’t forget to enable `app.UseSession();` to be able to use session.

Comment: Thank You! Your suggestion worked as a charm.